# Can I convert a Windows 7 Enterprise license for home use?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license

Here's the deal:

I have a laptop which was legitimately given to me when I left my old company 6 months ago - it's an old Lenovo T61, and it has Windows 7 Enterprise loaded on it. They were upgrading everyone's laptop at the point when I left, and they just told me to keep it...

I recently decided to turn it on (I haven't touched it since I left), and it's giving me all sorts of Windows activation  warnings. I assume this is because it can't access a volume license server on the company network?

2 questions:

1. How long can I continue to use it once the warnings have started showing up? Will it just stop working at some point, until I properly (re)activate Windows? Or will it just continue to whine about the fact that my copy of Windows isn't genuine, but still work fine?
2. Can I somehow 'convert' this license to a proper usable Windows 7 license (even Windows 7 Home)? Ideally legally - as much as I'm no M$ fanboy, I'd like to stay within the law and not try downloading warez.

As an additional point, Office says it will stop working imminently. No biggie - I really just plan to use this as a music server - but it would be nice to be able to use Word.

If the worst comes to the worst, I guess I can load Ubuntu or something like that, but I'd really prefer not too, as it's not as usable for my daughter or wife...

I don't really mind the regular "This copy of Windows is not genuine" warnings, but I don't want to invest time and money (this thing only has 2GB RAM, so I'm gonna need to spend $30 to get another 2GB, I think) if it's going to just stop working after a month until I activate Windows.

This question has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find an exact match. Apologies if this isn't clear, or if I'm duplicating an asked & answered question...

Comment: Its not possible to change an Enterprise installation to something you can actually connect.  You would have to format the HDD and using your own license reinstall Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they transferred the license to you with appropriate paperwork submitted to Microsoft, you do not have the right to continue using Enterprise.  The laptop had to ship with Windows 7 Pro - you have the right to reload that cleanly.  There should be a sticker with a key for pro on the laptop (unless it came with 8 Pro and was downgraded).  If you don't have the media and key and your old company won't give it to you, you'll have to buy it.  You must obtain media and keys legally.

*Licensing Disclaimer
License information provided here is "best efforts".  The comments of the respondents are based on interpretation of the license agreements and their knowledge of the particular laws and regulations in their geographic location.  Laws in your location may invalidate certain aspects of the license and/or licenses can change.  "They told me on StackExchange" will not be a valid excuse.  You need to contact the license granting authority to confirm any advice offered here.*